# Serving Angular with Appengine Java Servlets

Tags: java, angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm wanting to serve my Angular application on Java servlets on Google Appengine. Currently, I build the angular application with `ng b` (have also tried `ng b --prod`. This builds the application into the `/webapp` folder.

To deploy, I use a `gcloud app deploy`. The app deploys successfully, though if I try to go to any routing other than `/`, it'll throw a 404 error. This is expected with Angular.

I tried adding a property to my `web.xml` file to redirect everything back to Angular's `index.html` this way:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>html-mapping</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.html</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>html-mapping</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

This solution works locally, but doesn't work when deployed on Appengine. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Sever angular build with java is not a good choice. Let me know if you are able to change this approach. Anyway if you want to use java, you need several java classes. Do you have a java project?

Comment: JRichardsz yeah I get that I would love to not use this implementation, but things are out of my control. Yes there is already a Java project built up of various servlets and deploys and works fine, just this routing issue is hindering me

Comment: Are you able to use nodejs in your app engine? If yes, could you try with this https://github.com/utec/geofrontend-server ? Is a nodejs server implementation to server assets generated by react, angular, vue, etc. PLease share your java app to help you!

Comment: I believe that the problem is that you are trying to redirect to a file that is not a .jsp, so, in order to do that you would need to do something similar to what is proposed on this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16038301/12857703) or simply by changing your file to a .jsp extention, as a test. Let me know if this solves the issue.